# who to connect two android emulators runnnig on same machine?

Tags: android

i would like some help on sending some data between two emulators.they all speak about port forwarding but i cant make it work .the emulators have the id 5554 and 5556.and i know the listening port of each emulator.

what to write in order to sent message between the two emuators??

Comment: Did you read: [Interconnecting Emulator Instances](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#connecting)

Comment: @AlexJasmin yes and I have no idea what it's asking me to do

Comment: For future travelers who are left confused: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56519834/2413303

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send message then use the emulator's port no as sender's no then you can send sms to another emulator
check out 
http://learnandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/sms-emulation-on-android.html