# Communication between two Android emulators

Tags: java, android

My machine is running on  window 7.
I want to communicate between two android emulator's running on same machine.
Emulator first is listening on some IP 10.0.2.15
When second emulator tries to create

`Socket socket = new Socket ("10.0.2.15",8080);`

It gives exception, unable to connect to 10.0.2.15
does any one know how to solve this problem?

**EDIT:** I've already read https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#connecting but it says

> On B's console, issue redir add tcp:8080:80

What does it mean by B's console, or where is B's console??

Comment: Older question, but there's a newer one that is very similar with a couple more answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118494/android-2-emulators-communicating

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is to install TELNET on your Windows 7 machine. For that, Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows Features On or Off -> Telnet Client (must be ticked).

Then, in `cmd` (command prompt), you can say `adb devices` (if the Android SDK is on your PATH), which returns identifiers such as `emulator-5554` and `emulator-5556`.

Now with telnet, you can access them with `telnet localhost 5554` or `telnet localhost 5556`.

[image: initial connection]

To get them to tell you which emulator it is, you can type `avd name`.

But more importantly, it tells you this:

```
Android Console: Authentication required
Android Console: type 'auth <auth_token>' to authenticate
Android Console: you can find your <auth_token> in
'C:\Users\[youruser]\.emulator_console_auth_token'
OK
```

Which is a text file that contains some random cryptic text.

You can copy paste that into the telnet like so:

```
auth cdPi82HewjZg
```

to which it will say `OK`, now you can actually run the command the documentation said.

[image: after auth]

Now you can say

```
redir add tcp:6000:4000
```

Which means: `if the emulator would receive something to Port 6000 from LocalHost, then it should receive it as 4000`

Which means your other emulator can connect to it through the `10.0.2.2` magic loopback IP by sending data to 6000, and it is the *other* emulator that will receive it, with port 4000.

[image: no session yet]

[image: joined session]

It also works not just for `tcp:` but also for `udp:`.

You can list `redir` and even remove redirections with `redir del`.

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry about lashing out last night, it really was 3 AM (eventually 5) and I really did find only 5 different answers that said nothing beyond "read the docs".

Comment: `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` -- after I deleted my admittedly crappy old answer, your opening material was no longer relevant. which is why I pruned it. Your answer is excellent! Plus, I'm impressed that you dredged up the old instructions for adding telnet to Windows 7. :-)

Comment: what should be the port number passed into server and client socket , if use same tcp:6000:4000

Comment: The emulator that is redirected to `6000:4000` should be the server socket at `4000`, and the client socket should try to connect to it at `6000`.

Comment: I know that this is old, but as other comments have said THIS is one of the few that are not just "go check the docs" I'm still struggling a bit with the socket server since I cannot seem to be able to bind it (ERADDRNOTAVAIL) is there another step apart from the telnet connection? I have tried to either connect from an emulator or from the host itself could maybe share the code used on the app that is working? (I pray for this to be seen @EpicPandaForce sorry for the inconvenience)

Comment: @Antonio there were no additional steps than what I documented here. That message you got sounds like the port you are trying to use is already in use by something else.

Answer (score 0):

There may be two reasons

1. As per my knowledge is concerned you have run is < 2.3 version
2. Add Internet permission
3. Try to run the server first say in emulator number 5554 and client (say) 5556
   then type

   ```
   telnet localhost 5554
   ```