# Is it possible to establish communication between two Android Emulators using TCP

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android 2 emulators communicating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118494/android-2-emulators-communicating)

Is it possible to set up two emulators with a TCP connection to send strings from one to the other? Thank you