# how to connect two emulator instances on the same machine and transfer data(a file) between them?

Tags: android, ftp, emulation

Here it goes.

There are two emulator instances say A and B on same machine that is connected to internet. 
Now I need to transfer a file between A and B. How do I do that ?

I writing a ftp might make sense .. but am not sure of how the ports and ips would be. 
are there any thing that Android supports for easy file transfer ? (Should work between emulators)

It would be great to know all the ways to do it..
Thanks

Comment: For future travelers who were left confused: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56519834/2413303

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How to communicate between two Android emulators is explained in http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html:

> **Interconnecting Emulator Instances**
>
> To allow one emulator instance to communicate with another, you must
> set up the necessary network redirections as illustrated below.
>
> Assume that your environment is
>
> - A is you development machine
> - B is your first emulator instance, running on A
> - C is your second emulator instance, running on A too
>
> and you want to run a server on B, to which C will connect, here is how
> you could set it up:
>
> 1. Set up the server on B, listening to 10.0.2.15:
> 2. On B's
>    console, set up a redirection from A:localhost: to
>    B:10.0.2.15:
> 3. On C, have the client connect to
>    10.0.2.2:
>
> For example, if you wanted to run an HTTP server, you can select  as 80 and  as 8080:
>
> - B listens on 10.0.2.15:80
> - On B's console, issue redir add tcp:8080:80
> - C connects to 10.0.2.2:8080

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes. I figured it out and did this with some redir commands in telnet... Thanks anyways

Comment: It'd be nice if I knew ***where*** to run these telnet ops. I feel like https://xkcd.com/979/ because I've looked at multiple answers, it's been 8 years and I still have no idea. Yay.

Comment: I found out and documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278037/communication-between-two-android-emulators