# Establishing communication between two emulators in android

Tags: android, console, emulation

[how to connect two emulator instances on the same machine and transfer data(a file) between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261036/how-to-connect-two-emulator-instances-on-the-same-machine-and-transfer-dataa-fi)

I'm trying to establish communication between two emulators running on the same machine and I looked into the question above. But I don't find a way to redirect from the localhost ie., A:localhost to the second emulator(ie., B). I also dont know how to open console in the emulator. Any help would do good.

Comment: Open a console on the emulator for what purpose? You can use `adb shell` on the device you're trying to execute commands on.

Comment: So is there a way to do the redirection with adb shell, as mentioned in the link above?

Comment: yup... `adb <serialNumber> shell`

Comment: i need to redirect 10.0.2.2(my computer's local address) to 10.0.1.15 (emulator's local adddress) to establish commuunication. How to set up this redirection? I don't find any useful links to help me through this.